# Typescript: Anyone have an elegant way to take in a date string with a known timezone and convert it to UTC

Tags: node.js, typescript, date, momentjs

This issue has been gone over a thousand times but none of the answers successfully do this very simple thing in Typescript. I have an American Central/Chicago (UTC-5 or -6 depending on DST) time date string entering my service from an integrator that looks like this:

```
"May 25, 2021 04:39:54 PM"
```

This date string format is always going to enter my system in this shape, and luckily it IS accepted by a new Date constructor, but just using Date is proving to be futile.  My node service handles everything as UTC.  I need to take "May 25, 2021 04:39:54 PM" and get into a Date object that is UTC so I can consume/compare/etc.

It seems so simple, but I cannot find a working example for Typescript.  I want something that is simple that will adjust the time for me like:

```
const utcDate = new someDateLib("May 25, 2021 04:39:54 PM", "Central/Chicago");
```

Does anyone have an elegant solution for this?

Comment: Did you tried to use DayJS?

Comment: @GabrielLopes no I'll check it out though, assuming it has types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html) you could do something like:

```
const jsDateInChicago = DateTime.fromFormat(
  "May 25, 2021 04:39:54 PM",
  "LLLL dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a",
  { zone: "Central/Chicago" }
).toJSDate()
```

The first argument is the string to parse, the second argument describes the date format of the first argument, and the third lets you specify the time zone that this timestamp is from.

Comment: This looks promising.  I think i just need a ".toUTC()" before that ".toJsDate()" and I'm all set.

Comment: Yeah, or `.toUTC().toFormat("MM d, yyyy hh:mm:ss a")` would get you the timestamp back as a string in the same format it started, but this time in UTC

Comment: Getting some errors but if this works out I'll post what worked here.   I actually specifically don't want string output, we output all of our dates as full ISO long strings and require our clients to send the same as UTC.   This is a weird case though, where we have to consume reports that we can't force to be UTC because we are the consumer not the provider.   **Sigh**